# Cannot fit all the tabs of flexible text length within a div of fixed size

Tags: html, css

i have a header menu for an website. Lets take it has 9 tabs, two of which should be large in width while others are short text. I want all the tabs to adjust their width within the div and looks even. Can you please help me on this. Thank you.

> HTML

```
<div id="header_menu" align="center">
<ul >
<li><a href="#">Items </a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Inventory Inspection</a>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Orders</a>
</li>  
..
..
```

> CSS

```
#header_menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#header_menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
#header_menu ul li a {
    color: #CCC;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 20px;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-right-style: inset;
    border-bottom-style: inset;
    border-right-color: #CCC;
    border-bottom-color: #CCC;
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
}
#header_menu {
    width: 80%;
}
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: `I want all the tabs to adjust their width within the div and looks even` what do you mean looks even? As in each block is the same width? or each block has the same amount of padding? or all blocks fits the entire width of the container regardless of their width/padding? Please edit your question to clarify this

Comment: Also, there is no point defining `display: inline-block` and `float: xxx` on the same element

Comment: sorry for the confusion.. by saying looks even i meant to say that all the tabs should have balanced share of the total div width.. like the one that needs longer width it will have longer, the shorter will have shorter width, but they should look symmetric, balanced

Comment: also i have attached one picture trying to make you understand of what i want and what i'm getting. Please have a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `display: inline-block` on your list elements, you might consider using `min-width`, and percentage values, rather than fixing them at 115px.

Or you could set each list item to `display: table-cell`.

Comment: I have set the list item to display: table-cell   but not getting the desired result. I have attached an image trying to give you a better idea of my expected result. Please have a look. thank you.

Comment: @user3378974 try setting the `ul` to display table and the `li` to display table-cell, Give the `ul` width 100%. Make sure you remove the float from your `li` and anchor tags, here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/xu6ed9ge/

Comment: also @Huangism , i have some other requirement too. I have opened another issue regarding that requirement, which is related to this. I fyou kindly have a look at that problem, i will be really greatful.thank you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441808/cannot-make-menubar-dropdown-hover-properly