# Cannot make menubar dropdown hover properly

Tags: css, html

I have a menu bar which has 8 to 9 menus horizontally of different character length.
Also, each and every menu has sub menus of different character length.

All I want is -
    1. all the menus should be across the page (should fill the html body width that i have decided)
    2. all the sub menus should be drop down and will be of same width like as the parent menu width.

All i can do is, i have stretched menu bar so that it can fill the html body width and they took symmetrical width. but i cannot make the sub menus to be drop down one after another.
I have also attched examplary pictures of what i want

> HTML

```
<div id="header_menu">
<ul >
<li><a href="#">Product Repository </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">File Upload</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Inventory Inspection</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reprint</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inventory Report</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Reports</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
    body
    {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align:center;

    }
```

> HTML is already provided. i'm providing the working CSS for me. hope
>   it else somebody else.

```
#header_menu {
    height: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
#header_menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
}

#header_menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 597;
}
#header_menu ul li ul li a {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
#header_menu ul li:hover ul li a {
    height: 10%;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}


#header_menu ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#header_menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Meiryo, "Meiryo UI", "Microsoft Sans Serif", "MS Outlook";
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-right-width: thin;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-right-style: inset;
    border-bottom-style: inset;
    border-right-color: #999;
    border-bottom-color: #999;
}
#header_menu ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#header_menu ul li a:hover {
    font-family: Meiryo, "Meiryo UI", "Microsoft Sans Serif", "MS Outlook";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Can you post all relevant CSS? What you have doesn't even make the elements float the width of the window

Comment: I agree, we need more code.

Comment: A fiddle would be even easier...

Comment: sorry for this. I have posted the entire css related to that. I request you to kindly have a look into that. Although i have 8-9 menus, i have only posted 3 menus as an example in the html code. If those 3 menus can be fitted and their sub menus can be aligned properly, then i believe it would be same for 9 menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4zdbogah/4/) toked from [CSS Menu Maker site](http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/flat-dropdown-menu-tutorial)

I made some little changes to simplify example.
*Little update, nothing special*

**Update (fiddle too):**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Product Repository </a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">File Upload</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Inventory Inspection</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reprint</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inventory Report</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Reports</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>   
  </ul>
</div>
```

and css :

```
        #cssmenu {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {position: relative; z-index: 597; }
#cssmenu ul li { float: left; min-height: 1px; vertical-align: middle; border:solid 1px blue; width:150px;}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default; background-color:yellow;}
#cssmenu ul ul {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598; width: 150px;}
#cssmenu ul ul li {float: none; margin-left:-1px; width:150px; border:solid 1px red;}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul {bottom: 0; left: 0;}
#cssmenu ul ul {margin-top: 0; }
#cssmenu ul ul li {font-weight: normal;}
#cssmenu a { display: block; /*line-height: 1em;*/ text-decoration: none; }
```

It's not pretty but You can see the point.

**Update (code changed):**

```css
#cssmenu
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
a {text-decoration:none; color:black; width:100%; box-sizing:border-box; display:block;}
#cssmenu ul
{
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  cursor:default;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border:solid 1px gray;
}
#cssmenu ul li, #cssmenu ul li:last-child
{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
  border-right:solid 1px gray;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li:last-child {border:none;}
#cssmenu ul li:hover {background-color:yellow;}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {color: red;}
#cssmenu ul ul
{
  visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  margin:0;
  margin-left:-1px;
  z-index:101;
  display:block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li, #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child
{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 border:none;
 border-bottom:solid 1px gray;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child {border:none;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover
{
  background-color:navy;
}
#cssmenu ul li li:hover > a {color:white;}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {visibility:visible;}
```

```html
<div id='cssmenu'>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Product Repository </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">File Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Inventory Inspection</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reprint</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inventory Report</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>   
    <li><a href="#">Product Repository </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">File Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Inventory Inspection</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reprint</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inventory Report</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>   
    <li><a href="#">Product Repository </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">File Upload</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Inventory Inspection</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reprint</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inventory Report</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Repository </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search & Edit</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>   
   </ul>
</div>
```

Try this solution, but when You `Run code snippet` switch it to `Full Page`. I hope so this is what You want. But, always but, if Your window is too small, You can't avoid item values in two rows.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. but what i see in fiddle that the sub menu width a bit larger than the parent menu width. Don't know, if it is easier to modify, but sub menu blocks should be of same width as the parent menu

Comment: @user3378974 I update my answer. Try now. btw. be aware this example is with fixed width (`150px` in this example). You have to adapt for Your needs.

Comment: well.. thank you very much for your effort. But this doesn't exactly meet the need actually. 
May be i couldn't clarify the issue.if the width is 150px or any fixed length, that won't serve the purpose.because, when i actually implement it to my issue, there are 9 menus like 'product Repository' in example and each of them are of varying length.

Comment: now, say if i split the width into 100% /9, then each menu will get 11.1 % width.Now, say 'inventory inspection' needs 15% width to write the whole phrase
 into single line, whereas 'info' menu would only need 7% width, 
 just for the sake of example. So, if the width is fixed, then 'inventory Inspection' wouldn't fit in single line. this is the issue.

Comment: I would like to see 'inventory Inspection' is taking whatever width it requires(15%) and 'Info' is taking a smaller width as it doesn't need much.And the whole menu fits 
within the 100%.

Comment: @user3378974 hi there... I update my solution, answer ... run code snippet bit switch it to Full page. All horizontal menus will be autosized so there would not be menu item value in two rows. Submenu will be exactly `with` like they parent horizontal menu item.